# Did I just nuke my drive while doing a FAT32 to NTFS conversion?

Tags: partitioning, ntfs, partition-recovery, fat32, repair

I got a 2TB external HDD which was pre-formatted as `FAT32`. I had assumed  `exFat` and did not bother to check until I ran into the 4GB limit error and realized it was `FAT32`.

As a last stop, I ran a conversion to `NTFS`, and while doing so the PC froze and had to be rebooted. After reboot I had a `NTFS` partition, but all my data had gone bad. I can see the files are of the same size. I can open txt but apart from txt all files are corrupt. Somehow I feel that this maybe some kind of header issue? I ran a `file repair` utility on one of the  thousand+ odd files. It fixed the file but I can't be doing this on 10K+ files. That's asking for time and CPU. Is there a way to fix this en-masse ?

Comment: You mean to say you changed the file system type on this drive while *it had data*? It's surprising *anything* survived the "conversion". Just format the HDD and restore from your last disk backup.

Comment: Before reformatting, you might be able to run a file rescue program. There are quite a few, you'll have to Google them but essentially these programs scan disks and reconstruct files from there onto another drive, so you will need free space somewhere because rescuing software can't touch the drive since they assume anything could be data not yet recovered. There probably is no other way since it's impossible to know what state the drive was at the point of reboot.

Comment: That is when I have overwritten data those restore programs would be useful here no data has been overwritten there was a dynamic file system conversion that was permissibly  happening and it hosed . But there is regularity in which these files all have got corrupted the file size is the same there is something messed up while conversion was happening but It messed up pervasively but in a regular manner. So I kind of was hinting towards repair and Restoration more than recovery which would be a long drawn process looking at the data

Comment: As always in such cases, the real answer is "restore from backups".

Comment: My backups are in various places  & dont want to go through that rigmarole again. There is def. something quick and sleight of hand that should work & I am missing it and that's why I asked

Comment: Well, that's a problem. If your backup isn't restorable in an acceptable timeframe then your backup strategy is no good. But it's good that you have any! Draw conclusions from this mishap and take them into account in the future. My rule of thumb is to never mess with partitions and filesystems before making sure my backups are up to date.

Comment: @DrMoishe: There are tools which can build a new filesystem while preserving existing files. Windows actually comes with one – `convert.exe`. (Back in the days of WinNT 4, if you chose to install to NTFS, it would still install on FAT32 first followed by automatically converting it to NTFS.)

Comment: sorry if I was unclear. I used  that inbuilt `fat32` to `ntfs` conversion that tanked my drive. Precisely what I used. - the dynamic conversion

Comment: Try chkdsk in elevated cmd to see whether it fixes your problem or not, if you don't know these, a little Googling wouldn't hurt.

Comment: @XeнεiΞэnвϵς That's a potentially harmful advice. `chkdsk` could reclaim some of the previously-allocated disk space and overwrite it, destroying file data.

Comment: What is that file repair utility you used? Does it accept commands? If it works on one of the files, it is possible it will work on all the files, you can just write a script to let it automatically fix all files, I can help you writing the script.