# Data repair for a FAT32 drive that failed dynamic conversion to NTFS

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, filesystems, data-recovery, ntfs

I used this command

```
"CONVERT F: /FS:NTFS".
```

where `F:` is a 1Tb FAT32 formatted drive. Process hung and  had to close it. After that my files sizes remained same but they were corrupt & the rest of the drive is NTFS formatted so I can't re-run that command.

I tried various data recovery softwares to see if they can be repaired. No avail.

I am sure there's something I can do to those files which appear to be in not 100% NTFS format to make them come right.

I looking for a file repair solution as against recovery- there must be a FS header in them that was messed up during the conversion and I am hoping that can be reversed.

Comment: The problem is that you cancelled the conversion before it finished and there is no way to know what is valid data and what is not. You might be able to use something like [testdisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) to scan and recover the data to another disk. You'd probably want to scan it as a fat32 disk.

Comment: You seem to have [done this before](https://superuser.com/questions/1613086/did-i-just-nuke-my-drive-while-doing-a-fat32-to-ntfs-conversion). If you have already had trouble in the past then i would have thought that would have encouraged you to make sure you have adequate backups in case of failure.

Comment: Lesson learned: Back up a drive before messing with it? You could have copied the drive over to a new drive, then converted either drive and been able to copy it back if the conversion didn't work

Comment: Re-making a storage format is a risky business; the only "safe" way is to get a replacement device, set it up in the new way and COPY the files over.

Comment: yah it is the same drive I wanted to see if there is a way to repair the data as against do data recovery which is very lengthy before I rec format that disc. so I am trying to understand why this question what could change in those files so that they can be made readable again because not much seems to have changed. correct my earlier questions got no answer. my drive is lying idol and before I attempt that tedious data recovery I want to see if it is simply possible to repair and get my data in order.  Please   excuse my   ⌨️ typos  

Answer (score 1):

> I am sure there's something I can do to those files which appear to be in not 100% NTFS format to make them come right.

Of course you can do that. You will have to learn the structures of FAT32 and NTFS. Next thing is to reverse engineer the "convert" command. That requires operating system, assembler and disassembler knowledge.
You might find out that Microsoft cached the valuable metadata somewhere on your source disk and is somewhere saving progress data. Depending on your abstraction abilities that will take weeks, months or even years.

Therefore people having those abilities never move and resize partitions, nor do they convert file systems because caution requires to copy them first or use a new disk that can be partitioned and formated as needed. Using a new disk only requires one copy operation per file and allows to compare source and target.

Furthermore any erroneous code in file copy operations will be quickly discovered by as opposed to possible errors in the "convert" command.

> I looking for a file repair solution as against recovery- there must be a FS header in them that was messed up during the conversion and I am hoping that can be reversed.

The fact that you are trying to do "file repair" which is another term for overwriting a source information without being able to unwind the write operation in case of repair failure is unfortunately showing that your incident did not trigger a learning process in your mind.

"File repair" is as risky as every dangerous operation mentioned above.

Testdisk, as recommended by Mokubai is my recommendation as well and may it be just to ensure that Testdisk fails in doing the job.
Then you can enjoy trying out a bunch of recovery software hoping that this software is able to evaluate the remains of metadata.

Be aware that such software expects the remains that fit to one file system and not two - a real bad trap you fell into.
If such software fails, that practically means that you lost the chance of recovering metadata like file names, length etc.

Then you are left with Photorec (part of the Testdisk package).
Photorec can do miracles but only if you used your drive data grave style - only writing, never deleting.
If your file system is fragmented due to a lot of delete and write operations your intended repair is pretty much like solving a puzzle based on cluster information and not parts of pictures.

Comment: If you meant to say in so many words .... what I did was senesless... Your right,I screwed up ( Sunday Morning - hangover from Sat night ... I woke up half awake as if thinking MS stuff works way its supposed to....so yeah My fault ..ok & yourself & the communty here may feel free to flag me down on the queston. But this is a situation many ppl are left with.We dont think through until it happened  so hopefully with so much  tart I got from others probably with better K then me...it wll help others out i nthe same situation ( I still 1 up that ans thx.Later on when all ans come will tick it )